# Integral of $\sec(3x)$ between certain variable limits.

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_x^{x+\frac{\pi }{8}} \frac{1}{\cos (3 t)} \, dt$$

I get:
$$\frac{1}{3} \, \log\left(\sec\left(3x + \frac{3\pi}{8} \right)+\tan\left(3x+ \frac{3\pi}{8} \right) \right) - \frac{1}{3} \, \log(\sec(3x) + \tan(3x))$$

I can't make that look nice, though, and I'm supposed to be drawing a graph :/

Comment: please try to format things using MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Your equation is poorly stated.  It makes little sense to have $x$ as the integration variable *and* as the limits of integration.  Please fix the problem (and use *MathJax*).

Comment: $$\frac{1}{3} \log \left((1-\sin (3 x)) \cot \left(\frac{1}{16} (\pi -24 x)\right) \sec (3 x)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider first the antiderivative
$$I=\int \sec (3t)\,dt =\frac 13\int \sec (u)\,du  \qquad \text{with} \qquad u=3t$$  Now, the tangent half-angle substitution
$$\int \sec (u)\,du=2\int \frac {dv}{1-v^2}\qquad \text{with} \qquad u=2 \tan ^{-1}(v)$$ Partial fraction decomposition to get
$$2\int \frac {dv}{1-v^2}=\log (1+v)-\log (1-v)=-\log \left(\frac{1-v}{1+v}\right)$$
Back to $u$ $(v=\tan \left(\frac{u}{2}\right))$
$$\frac{1-v}{1+v}=\frac{1-\tan \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)}{1+\tan \left(\frac{u}{2}\right)}=\frac{\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)-\tan \left(\frac{u}{2}\right) } {1+\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\tan \left(\frac{u}{2}\right) }=\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac u2 \right)$$ Back to $t$ $(u=3t)$
$$I=-\frac 13\log \left(\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{3 t}{2}\right)\right)=\frac 13\log \left(\cot \left(\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{3 t}{2}\right)\right)$$ Now, using the bounds (do not forget the absolute values - being lazy, I did not ype them in the preliminary calculations)
$$\int_x^{x+\frac{\pi }{8}} \frac{1}{\cos (3 t)} \, dt=\frac 13\log \left(\Big|\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{16}-\frac{3 x}{2}\right) \tan \left(\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{3
   x}{2}\right)\Big|\right)$$